# Price parsing in python - How to split all strings in a list once before the first occurrence of any digit?

Tags: python, string, list-comprehension

I have a list of strings that looks like this:

**Input:**

```
prices_list = ["CNY1234", "$ 4.421,00", "PHP1,000", "€432"]
```

I want to remove everything except .`isdigit()`, and `'.|,'`. In other words, I would like to split before the first occurrence of any digit with `maxsplit=1`:

**Desired output:**

```
["1234", "4.421,00", "1,000", "432"]
```

**First attempt (two regex replacements)**:

```
# Step 1: Remove special characters
prices_list = [re.sub(r'[^\x00-\x7F]+',' ', price).encode("utf-8") for price in prices_list]
# Step 2: Remove [A-Aa-z]
prices_list = [re.sub(r'[A-Za-z]','', price).strip() for price in prices_list]
```

**Current output:**

```
['1234', '$ 4.421,00', '1,000', '432']   # $ still in there
```

**Second attempt (still two regex replacements):**

```
prices_list = [''.join(re.split("[A-Za-z]", re.sub(r'[^\x00-\x7F]+','', price).encode("utf-8").strip())) for price in price_list]
```

This (of course) leads to the same output as my first attempt. Also, this isn't much shorter and looks very ugly. Is there a better (shorter) way to do this?

**Third attempt (list comprehension/nested`for`-loop/no regex):**

```
prices_list = [''.join(token) for token in price for price in price_list if token.isdigit() or token == ',|;']
```

**which yields:**

```
NameError: name 'price' is not defined
```

How to best parse the above-mentioned price list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to leave only specific characters, it's better to tell regex to do exactly that thing:

```
import re

prices_list = ["CNY1234", "$ 4.421,00", "PHP1,000", "€432"]

prices = list()
for it in prices_list:
    pattern = r"[\d.|,]+"
    s = re.search(pattern, it)
    if s:
        prices.append(s.group())

> ['1234', '4.421,00', '1,000', '432']
```

Answer (score 1):

### The Problem

Correct me if I'm wrong, but essentially you're trying to remove symbols and such and only leave any trailing digits, right?

> I would like to split before the first occurrence of any digit

That, I feel, is the simplest way to frame the regex problem that you are trying to solve.

### A Solution

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re

# Match any contiguous non-digit characters
regex = re.compile(r"\D+")

# Input list
prices_list = ["CNY1234", "$ 4.421,00", "PHP1,000", "€432"]

# Regex mapping
desired_output = map(lambda price: regex.split(price, 1)[-1], prices_list)
```

This gives me `['1234', '4.421,00', '1,000', '432']` as the output.

### Explanation

The reason this works is because of the lambda and the map function. Basically, the map function takes in a lambda (a portable, one-line function if you will), and executes it on every element in the list. The negative index takes the last element that the list of matches that the `split` method generates

Essentially, this works because of the assumption that you don't want any initial non-digits in your output.

### Caveats

- This code not only keeps `.` and `,` in the resulting substring, but **all** characters in the resulting substring. So, an input string of `"$10e7"` will be output as `'10e7'`.
- If you were to have just digits and `.` and `,`, such as `"10.00"` as an input string, you would get `'00'` in the corresponding location in the output list.

If none of these are desired behavior, you would have to get rid of the negative indexing next to the `regex.split(price, 1)` and do further processing on the resulting list of lists so that you can handle all of those pesky edge cases that arise with using regex.

Either way, I would try and throw more extreme examples at it just to make sure that it's what you need.